# matInput Label Hiding on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-input

I just started using Angular Material.
I copied a code from [Official Material Input](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) docs.

But, whenever I focus on the input, it hides when it floats.

[Before Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Q8F.png)

[After Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C6s8.png)

P.S. : It happens on every form field and input.
Please Help Me.

Thank You

EDIT:

I have created a material module in which I import all the necessary modules related to material and then export it to app.module.ts

material.module.ts

```js
...
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
...

const MaterialComponents = [
    ...
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ...
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ MaterialComponents ],
    exports : [ MaterialComponents ]
})
```

app.module.ts

```js
...
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule, MediaChange, MediaObserver } from "@angular/flex-layout";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        routingComponents,
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ...

        /* Material Imports */
        MaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        NgbModule,
    ],
    providers: [ Title ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

home.component.html

```js
<form class="form">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
            <input matInput [formControl]="emailFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com">
            <!-- <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint> -->
            <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
                Please enter a valid email address
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
                Email is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Save</button>
    </form>
```

It's just copied from Official Material Docs

Node version is @12.16.2

Angular version is @9.1.3

Comment: hard to help without showing code! 
did you add this to your app.module: import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

Comment: @Lys I have updated the question with required files. Please let me know if you need any other files.

Comment: any error in your console, or css that is messing around with it? I just made a small app in stackblitz and all worked properly

Comment: Yes, There is a version mismatch warning.
```
Your global Angular CLI version (9.1.3) is greater than your local
version (9.1.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
```

Does it occur due to this warning?

Comment: @Lys I updated my local angular version. But still, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out.
I wrote this due to horizontal overflow in toolbar

styles.css

```css
* {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The Issue was solved after I removed the css property.